# Windows 10 Pro Installation on Macbook air failing with error that it cant update the boot configuration

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

Good Day, I have seen this question asked on several differnt forums but I just cant get it to work.

I have a brand new Macbook Air Retina 13" (2019) with all the updates, running Catalina (10.15.1).

I am trying to install windows 10 Professional using bootcamp but keep getting errors.

Process I am following:
-run bootcamp,

- select partition size
- provide iso (have tried Builds 1706, 1809 and 1903)
- mac downloads,
- PC restarts
- I go through the installation wizard
- windows installs all files
- downloads updates

I then get the below error message:
"Windows could not update the computers boot configuration"

Installation obviously fails.
I have tried different iso's, ensureing MAC is up to date, even reinstalled MAC OS from a freshly cleaned partition.

I have tried repeating the process, PRAM reset, hard power resets, changing USB etc and all the same :-(

I have also tried to boot from a Windows USB boot disk but it obviously cant seee the MAC hard drive so cant install.

Any ideas how I can get this to work through boot camp

OR

the windows driver for the MAC hard drive that Windows will recognize during a fresh install?

I am not sure what else I can try.

Thank you for the help.

[image]

Comment: I believe there were no Catalina compatible Boot Camp drivers and that Apple (has already, or...) will soon update Boot Camp so it will work with Catalina

Comment: I have installed just yesterday on my Macbook having Catalina. I got an issue in the beginning but repeat the same step again after rebooting, and it worked. Let me try to look at it if I can provide any fix for you.

Comment: @Smudger: I guess you are not trying 32bit Windows 10 ?

Comment: @Udhy, nope, 64bit.

Comment: I actually just came right after 3 days of fighting, I used version 1903 and repeated the process. I cant tell you what the actual issue was but is resolved now. 1903 didnt work the first time I tried so am not sure on the root cause sadly.

Comment: I phone Apple South Africa for the correct version and they referred me to Microsoft who referred be to Apple :-(

Comment: I used 1909 and it worked perfectly without any issue till now. Try 1909